# Remove similar(but not the same) strings in a single list

Tags: python, recursion, fuzzywuzzy

I have a list of strings that look like:

```py
my_list = ['https://www.google.com/', 'http://www.google.com/', 
           'https://www.google.com',  'http://www.google.com']
```

As you can see they are not the same but they all look very similar.

I also have a function which is:

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def similar(a, b):
    return fuzz.ratio(a,b)
```

I want to use this functions and say something like:

```py
for a,b in my_list:
    print (a,b)
    if similar(a,b) > 0.95:
        my_list.remove(b)
```

So I'm trying to remove similar looking strings from a list if they are above a certain similarity ratio. I want to do this so that in this list I would end up with just the first url, in this case `my_list` would end up being:

```py
my_list = ['https://www.google.com/']
```

Comment: Do you deal with urls only?

Comment: Yes, but I think I found a solution.

Comment: Comparing URLs by using [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) might be a good starting point. A more rudimentary approach would be a `string.rstrip('/')` to remove the `/` at the end of the URL and then convert the list to a set since sets do not support duplicates and drop duplicate entries automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some googling, I found fuzzywuzzy has an inbuilt function which is pretty great.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy.process import dedupe

deduped_list = list(dedupe(my_list, threshold=97, scorer=fuzz.ratio))
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you should never use `list.remove()` within an iteration loop, because the list iterator will get confused when you remove an item from the same list you are iterating over.

And because you always want to keep the first item you can exclude it from the loop:

```
idx = 1
while idx < len(my_list):
    if similar(my_list[idx - 1], my_list[idx]) > 0.95:
        my_list.remove(my_list[idx])

print(my_list)
```

## alternative solution with list comprehension

```
first_item = my_list[0]
my_list = [first_item] + [item for item in my_list[1:] if similar(first_item, item) <= 0.95]

print(my_list)
```